# RAM query vs Join

Tags: sql, join

Say we have 3 tables, `Customer`,`Subscription`,`Newspaper`, where `Subscription` is a relation between the other two. If we want the newspaper's names a certain individual subscribes to, we COULD make a query to get the list of all `Subscriptions`, producing an array called `allSubscription` then search, in RAM, the tuples that contain the Customer's id and retrieve a list of the newspaper's ids.

With that, we can get the list of all the newspapers' names querying the entire `Newspaper` table, getting a `allNewspaper` array, and searching, in RAM, the tuples that contain the ids we know that person has subscribed. This method is a simulation of a join, but with no join.

We learn very early that databases are optimized for such queries, and we should not use this method. However, what about the case we need such names for EVERY customer?

In this case, the traditional query would join 3 tables. If, however, we use the RAM search I just described, we would have 3 arrays, `allCustomers`, `allSubscriptions`, `allNewspaper`, in which seems to be, in total, less expensive than querying the join of the three tables. Finally, we have the result from a some fors, like, say:

```
ramSubs = {}
for c in allCustomers:
    ramSubs[c.id] = []
for s in allSubscriptions:
    ramSubs[s.customer_id].append(s.newspaper_id)
ramNews = {}    
for n in allNewspaper:
    ramNews[n.id] = n.name
for c in allCustomers:
    print c.name
    for c_id,n_id in ramSubs:
        print ramNews[n_id],
```

With that said, which approach is more adviced and efficient?

Comment: That's not SQL - so why the SQL tag?

Comment: My database is bigger than your RAM. It is also faster, mostly because it doesn't have to fetch *all* the records.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a nested loop join.  All databases definitely to implement nested loop joins, along with a variety of other methods.

If you have three "tables", then presumably these are stored in a SQL engine.  The best approach is to let the SQL engine process the data, identifying the best algorithm for it.

If you have the data in three arrays in memory, then you are not talking about a SQL engine.  You are just talking about implementing an efficient algorithm -- something database designers have been concerned with all along.  (That said, a bespoke algorithm for known data structures optimizes for the system where it is running is likely to be faster than the equivalent running in a database.)

Comment: Maybe I didnt myself clear. Yes they are SQL tables, i dont have them as ram arrays, but I CAN get such arrays with three "small" queries, instead of one nested join.